# Raspberry pi controlling servo with dotnet

Tags: windows, servo

Hello all i am trying control servo motor usiun dotnet and `Unosquare.RaspberryIO` librery. This is my code and whatever I pass to the `PayTone`method the motor rotates only in one direction and one speed. I am using `Pi 4b` and `FeeTech FS90R` motor.
If anyone can help

```
using Unosquare.RaspberryIO;
using Unosquare.RaspberryIO.Abstractions;
using Unosquare.WiringPi;

namespace projectV2
{
    public class ServoController : BaseClass
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            Pi.Init<BootstrapWiringPi>();

            var pin = Pi.Gpio[12];
            pin = Pi.Gpio[BcmPin.Gpio12];
            pin.PinMode = GpioPinDriveMode.Output;

            System.Device.Pwm.Drivers.SoftwarePwmChannel buzzerPwm =
                new System.Device.Pwm.Drivers
                .SoftwarePwmChannel(12, 1600, 0.5, false, new System.Device.Gpio.GpioController(), false);

            var buzzer = new Iot.Device.Buzzer.Buzzer(buzzerPwm);

            buzzer.PlayTone(1000, 1000);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            buzzer.PlayTone(1500, 1000);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            buzzer.PlayTone(2000, 1000);

            buzzer.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Now I try use `System.Device.Gpio` now my code looks like below. The code is executed to the end , but there no result to the gpio 12 (servo does not react )

```
using System;
using System.Device.Pwm;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Device.Gpio;

namespace projectV2
{
    public class ServoController : BaseClass
    {

        public async Task Test()
        {

            ServoMotor servoMotor = new ServoMotor(PwmChannel.Create(0, 0, 50, 0.5));

            servoMotor.Start();

            servoMotor.WritePulseWidth(1000);
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            servoMotor.WritePulseWidth(1500);
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            servoMotor.WritePulseWidth(2000);

            servoMotor.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give the servo 50 pulses per second (each between 1 and 2 milliseconds long).  Are you?

Comment: All i do is the code above.I am very new in that

Comment: Assuming GPIO 12 try the following.  `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs s 12 1000` then `pigs s 12 1400` then `pigs s 12 2000`.  What happens?

Comment: I try it , but the result is the same , only one direction

Comment: Either a faulty servo or you have not connected it to the correct GPIO.

Comment: It's on the right gpio. When I pass the frequency, it starts to spin. There is no way that happen if it is on the wrong gpio

Comment: If I pass duty cycle 0.9 and tone 25k , them start spin beckward, but obviously all my logic is wrong, so I will try to do it with ```System.Device.Gpio```

Comment: This does not make sense.  Need clear photo(s) showing the Pi and Servo and the connections between the Pi and the servo.

Comment: Use http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html or http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py to see the activity.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET library you are using is based on WiringPi which has been deprecated  for almost 2 years. The Pi4 version of WiringPi was never released in source so it is unlikely the unofficial port in the library you are using is fully operational.

I believe there is a version based on pigpio which would be a better option.

Comment: It's been a while, but now I'm getting back to the RaspberryPi and I'd be grateful if you could recommend a library !?